# Mobile web controls HTTP2 / SPDY support

Tags: android, ios, http2

I trying to figure out whether mobile web controls (e.g. WebView in Android and UIWebView in iOS) support HTTP2 (or depricated SPDY) protocols.

For some reason I can't find any documentation for that, will glad if anyone could direct me to some reference.

Comment: Yes for iOS. There have been various WWDC videos on the topic. If you do an Internet search you should find them.